# HTML first section take up whole page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the first initial first section to take up the whole height of the page.
I've tried this question here: [Making a div fit the initial screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286128/making-a-div-fit-the-initial-screen) but I cannot get it to work, everything just overlaps.

My nav bar is centered on the first section and will stick to the top when the page is scrolled, I just need the first part to take up the whole page.

Like this:

[image]

[Spotify also do it on their website](https://www.spotify.com/au/)

My HTML:
        
        
        
        Title

```
    <body>

    <span id="top"></span>


        <div id="floater"></div>
        <div id="centered">
        <div id="sticky_navigation_wrapper">
            <div id="sticky_navigation">
               <div class="navbar">
                    <a class="navbar" href="#about">about</a>   <a class="navbar" href="#portfolio">portfolio</a>   <a class="navbar" href="#top"><img src="/media/nav/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>  <a class="navbar" href="#social">social</a> <a class="navbar" href="#contact">contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div>
   <a>Random Text here, blah blah blah!</a>
   </div> 
   </body>
```

My CSS

```
html,body{
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#floater {
    position:relative; float:left;
    height:50%; margin-bottom:-25px;
    width:1px;
}

#centered {
    position:relative; clear:left;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#sticky_navigation_wrapper { 
width:100%; height:50px; 
}

#sticky_navigation { 
width:100%; height:50px; background-color:rgb(241, 241, 241); text-align:center; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make the web page height to fit screen height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868474/how-to-make-the-web-page-height-to-fit-screen-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution, which I use on sites like this, would be to wrap each section in a containing div (or , if all your target browsers support it or you don't mind using a html5 shiv).

like so

```
<div class="section">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

You can then give that div height: 100% and width: 100% like...

```
.section{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can see it all put together in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ucetz/

Answer (score 0):

I do this to my webpages all the time. Just add a containing div with the `position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;` style. That should give you a shade like area to cover the whole webpage. You can then put whatever you want inside that div.

To center vertically, do a little math and use a div. Thus, if the height of your div is going to be `400px` then make the `position: fixed` again with the same specifications above, except change the `top` to `50%` and then `margin-top` a negative value to half of the height. So, in this case it would be `margin-top: -200px;`

```
<div id="container" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<div id="otherstuff" style="position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 400px; margin-top: -200px;"> I am a verticall centered div! :)
</div>
</div>
```

and then for your navigation bar after you get passed the first layer, put that on `position: fixed;` as well, just make sure it is above the code given above. That way, it appears on the bottom.

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 70px; width: 100%;">Your navigation content</div> 
<!-- THE CODE GIVEN ABOVE SHOULD GO HERE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include height: 100% in the style for the HTML and BODY tags. Then set the height of the sections.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Viewport](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/) Height.
Set the height of your *div* (also works with *section*) to whatever percentage you want your div to fill up the screen.

```
.section_div {
   /* fill up 85% of screen heigth */
   height: 85vh;

   /* fill up 100% of screen width */
   width: 100vw;

   /* you can also use min-height instead of height. */
}
```